# Browser Contron With Javascript Detection and DOM Read

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, porting

I have a website designed for adaptive content, and need to make a "Desktop App", my idea is to insert the Website in a Windows Form, using a "browser" control, preferably chrome-like (The Website is in HTML5/CSS3).

My "problem" is that I need to handle "javascript events", I need to launch an event from the website, and the App would need to catch it and do something.

In another side, I need to read some DOM components via Class or ID, and read the attributes in the Windows App (like div content, or data-* attributes)

Does a free control exist for VB.NET with these capabilities?

Comment: [cefsharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) is a Chromium based control you can use.  You'd have to do further research into what it supports in regard to binding to events.

Comment: Im trying 2 engines cefsharp and awesomium, all are tooo slow, much more slow than the chrome browser. Its this the normal speed of embed component in .NET or is a problem with any parameter? In other side, the embed components dont use antialiasing, all webfont show ugly borders.

Comment: Finally, im using GeckoFX, component for use Firefox engine in .NET apps, its more fast (rendering CSS/HTML and loading) and works perfect. Only one point, the version 29 dont work the Web -> C# events, i download the v22 and work perfect from web -> C# and from C# -> web.